# A web-based video-conferencing system. Does this technology already exist?

Tags: video, audio, cross-platform

Is it possible with today's technologies to create a web-based video-conferencing system? If yes, how to access video/audio streams on a client from a web-browser? If no, what is the main obstacle?

Comment: How is this programming related? If I wanted to know the answer to this I'd google "web video conferincing"... and guess what!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is yes, it's been done countless times - usually with Flash.

Here's a non-porn example: http://tinychat.com/